# What kind of Software testing(Black-box or White-box) is done by django testcase classes?

Tags: automated-testing, unit-tests, whitebox-testing

In my django application, i haven't use model for database. I have traditional way of doing it, that is by mysql server and client. I have used MySQLdb for database access. 
Also in my django views, almost all code are written in normal python code, that is i have not used the advantage of django built in view classes and functions.

```
def showhome(request):

  if request.user.is_anonymous():       
      return HttpResponseRedirect("/")

  db = MySQLdb.connect(host=dbHost,port=dbPort,user=dbUser,passwd=dbPasswd,db=dbName)

  c = db.cursor()                                                                       
  username=request.user                                                                       
  c.execute("Select firstname from USER where USERNAME=%s,(username,))                     
  name=c.fetchone()
  c.close()

  firstname=name[0]                                                                         
  c=db.cursor()
  c.execute("Select vehicle,status from PROPERTY where firstname=%s,(firstname,))
  deviceDetails=c.fetchall()
  c.close()


  paginator = Paginator(deviceDetails, 10)                                                

  page = request.GET.get('page')
  try:
      List = paginator.page(page)   
  except PageNotAnInteger:
      List = paginator.page(1)      
  except EmptyPage:
      List = paginator.page(paginator.num_pages)       

  current=List.number              
  last_page=paginator.num_pages
  page_limit=10          
  n=current%page_limit

  if n==1:                                                                                        
      start=current                                                                       
  else:
      start=(current-n+1) if n!=0 else current-page_limit+1                               
  end=start+page_limit                                                                    
  if end>last_page:                                                                       
      end=last_page+1
  page_range=range(start,end)                                                             


  context={}
  context['Data']=List
  context['page_range']=page_range
  db.close()
  return render(request,"home/show.html",context)
```

What type of testing i have to do in tests.py file blackbox or whitebox?
If it is whitebox which type i have to follow for testing the above function unittest or integration test?
I think unittest is enough for the above function, isn't it?

Comment: This question isn't very clear; blackbox/whitebox tests are statements about your knowledge of the code, not the type of testing to be done.

Answer (score 1):

Terminology may be not that transparent and some might say that the database - is a dependency, authentication backend - is a dependency (hence, no testing in isolation that is in the "unit test" definition) and think of this kind of tests as "integration"/"functional"/"system".

On the other hand, Django and tools around it provide ways for you to use a [special test database](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/testing/overview/#the-test-database) which you can load with fixtures or generate the data for your models using factories (like [`factory-boy`](http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)).

And, you can also do both the black box (API testing - by triggering the url route configured for your view and analyzing the response) and the white box testing (which in this case would be your Django view tests).

Comment: I have done only unit test for this function. Writing unittest will cover the functionality also, am i right?. Here white box testing means unit testing since here we have only one function?

Comment: @vishnumc terminology should not be the focus here overall. Monitor code coverage and make sure you've covered the corner cases and important/possible code paths in the view. And yes, these tests are white box since you know the code under test and use this knowledge to test it. Thanks.